# Why did Yuuto try to dodge Rokuro's attacks?

Tags: twin-star-exorcists

In episode 42, Yuuto said that he took the spell power of Kuranashi, the 12 Guardians, and Abe no Seimei. Then why would he try to dodge Rokuro's attacks?

In episode 41, Kuranashi didn't need to dodge the attacks of Tatara.
Then how come when Yuuto combined all that power with the Guardians and Abe no Seimei, he needed to dodge Rokuro's single attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two hypothesis for that

1. He was bluffing. He did not take that much spell power. He would need to spend spell power to block the attacks that did land and/or regenerate wounds. He was saving on power. **Not likely.**
2. He wanted Rokuro to keep on fighting in order to enrage him into changing modes. If he just overpowered his attacks and shielded himself, maybe rokuro would stop fighting / enraging to think of a different strategy. No. He wants him to keep on swinging and slowly lose his humanity as his kegare side takes over. Once he realizes that this is not going so smoothly, he traps Benio and starts to kill her.

This is the most likely, as we see later that

> He indeed evolves, and is saved by the timely reappearance of Tsuchimikado Arima.